# Neuromorphic Computing should be changed to Neuromorphic engineering

Tags: bug, moderators

So I came across this tag `neuromorphic-computing` while editing a question. This is a quite misleading  name. I suggest the moderators change the name to `neuromorphic-engineering` which covers the entire field of chip design and not just computation, which was the main purpose for the emergence field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with this because [it is consistent with the wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuromorphic_engineering) for the field.

Comment: So when will it be changed? I'll try to add a definition to it

Comment: @DuttaA done.  (thanks for the reminder )